# Segmentation Fault accessing struct

Tags: c

I am not a C developer, however I have inherited some terrible C code that I need to compile. The code compiles, however appears to run into segmentation faults when the code accesses members of a struct. I have simplified the code for below, this is what is causing the seg faults, and I am unsure why, please help :).

```
typedef struct FOO {

   unsigned int  amount;

}FOO;

int main()
{
    FOO *foo1;
    FOO *foo2;

    unsigned int zero = 0;
    foo1->amount = zero;
    foo2->amount = zero;

    printf("\n1. amount: %u\n", foo1->amount);
    printf("2. amount: %u\n", foo2->amount);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to make `foo1` and `foo2` point to something (local variable, allocated memory) to access its values. Otherwise, what do you think it does when it tries `foo1->amount` and doesn't point to anything?

Comment: `FOO *foo1;` makes a pointer to a FOO that doesn't point anywhere.  You need to assign something to the pointer before using it.  So you can't `foo1->amount` until the pointer points to an actual FOO.  Why are you making it a pointer anyway?  Just do this: `FOO foo1; FOO foo2; foo1.amount = 0; foo2.amount = 0;`  If you really need a pointer then `FOO *foo1 = malloc(sieof(FOO)); FOO *foo2 = malloc(sieof(FOO));; foo1->amount = 0; foo2->amount = 0;` will work (but remember to call free for them).

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that in C when you have pointers they must point to allocated memory if you are to use them. In other words:

```c
int main()
{
    FOO *foo1 = calloc(1, sizeof(FOO));
    FOO *foo2 = calloc(1, sizeof(FOO));

    // Technically unnecessary since calloc() will zero by default
    unsigned int zero = 0;
    foo1->amount = zero;
    foo2->amount = zero;

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Though having variables of the form `x1`, `x2` etc. is an anti-pattern. Instead use arrays:

```c
int main()
{
    const int N = 2;
    FOO *foo = calloc(N, sizeof(FOO));

    // You can access in the range 0..(N-1) where N=2 above
    foo[0]->amount = ...;
    foo[1]->amount = ...;

    // Allows very easy iteration with for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      foo[i]->amount = ...;
    }

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

When you think in terms of *structured data* and not *code* you can get your code do to a lot more work for you.